# Avoid multiple function calls in Angular template

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the following code

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items">
    <button [disabled]="doSomething(item)"></button>
    <input [someProperty]="doSomething(item)"></div>
    <div [ngClass]="{
          'class1': item.attr == 'val1' || doSomething(item),
          'class2': row.attr != 'val2' && !doSomething(item)
        }"
></div>
```

in component

```
doSomething(item) {
    return someBooleanLogic(item);
}
```

I feel it is not a good practice to recalculate every time the `doSomething` value for each item in the template.

Is there a more recommended way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple ways around it, one of them being a template "hack":

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items">
  <ng-container *ngIf="{ something: doSomething(item) } as data">
    <button [disabled]="data.something"></button>
    <input [someProperty]="data.something"></div>
    <div [ngClass]="{
          'class1': item.attr == 'val1' || data.something,
          'class2': row.attr != 'val2' && !data.something
        }"></div>
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

Another way could be by adding a property to each `item` object when it is obtained, and read this property.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a huge amount of items, you can save time by calculating your BooleanLogic before in your Typescript code, save it in a list and loop through it.

Comment: Consider adding an example